# Как сделать так,чтобы при нажатии на изображение,на этой же странице высвечивался блок с описанием изображения?

Tags: jquery

Как сделать так,чтобы при нажатии на изображение,на этой же странице высвечивался блок с описанием этого изображения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это можно сделать на чистом CSS, если не принципиально, чтобы описание сохранялось до тех пор, пока на картинку не нажмут еще раз. Через `CSS:focus` - фокус выполняет указанные условия до тех пор, пока элемент активен. Как только кликнут где-нибудь в другом месте - пропадет.

[ДЕМО](https://liveweave.com/OF6hOu)

```
<button class="HINT"><img src="..."></button>

<div class="BUBU">Описание всякого</div>
```

Добавлена кнопка `<button>`, потому что она поддерживает фокус, а картинка - нет.
К описанию изначально приписывается невидимость:

```
.BUBU { display: none; }
```

А при клике на кнопку-картинку, добавляется видимость и дальнейший стиль:

```
.HINT:focus + .BUBU {display: inline-block;
                     position: absolute;
                     margin-top: 50px;
                     margin-left: 20px;
                     background-color: rgb(235, 160, 15);
                     padding: 5px;
                     border: 3px solid #800000;
                     box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white,0 0 0 3px #800000;
                     cursor: pointer;}
```

Абсолютная позиция позволяет свободно играть с margin и перемещать табличку куда надо, не задевая другие элементы на странице. А последние пять строчек добавлены чисто ради красоты, не обязательны.

Ну и, тоже для красоты, не обязательная стрелочка:

```
.BUBU:before {content: "◄"; 
              color: #f36700; 
              position: absolute;
              font-size: 50px;
              margin-left: -50px;
              margin-top: -20px;}
```

Точно также можно сделать всплывающее описание при наведении мышки. 
Код всё тот же, только заменить `:focus` на `:hover`

P.s. в CSS плюсик `.КЛАСС + .ВТОРОЙ` между классами означает "выдели тот класс .ВТОРОЙ, который находится непосредственно после .КЛАСС"

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
</style>    

<img src="/img.jpg" descSelector="#somedesc" onclick="toggledescription(this)" />
<div id="somedesc" class="hidden">Image description</div>

<script>
    function toggledescription(el) {
        var selector = el.getAttribute('descSelector');
        $(selector).toggleClass('hidden');
    }
</script>
```

Жуквери не забудь подключить

Comment: почему в консоли пишет welcome.html:59 Uncaught ReferenceError: toggledescription is not defined
    at HTMLImageElement.onclick (welcome.html:59)
onclick @ welcome.html:59?